# SQL: Convert Day Mon DD TIME TIMEZONE YYYY to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a string with date format, and I would like to convert it to the variable type datetime.

```
 Tue Apr 16 01:43:08 PDT 2013
```

I had the best luck by nesting replaces and removing the 3-Letter Day of the Week and the 3-Letter Time Zone, but then it stopped working.  I will investigate that part later this weekend...  I have also tried Convert and Cast.

How do I accurately convert the string to a datetime?

Bonus points if you can preserve the time zone and Daylights Savings Time information, but it is not necessary.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL *Flavor*)? Date/Time functions differ between implementations.

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Comment: It seems that you do need to re-assemble your string before conversion. If day of the month is a single digit, does your format include a leading zero? Is it "`Apr 1`" or "`Apr 01`"?

Comment: Thankfully it is preceded by a 0.  I will write a code to reassemble the date prior to conversion!  Thank you!!